# What does it mean for a closed source project to have a permissive licence (CC BY-NC)?

Tags: closed-source, binaries, cc-by-nc

Earlier today I was installing a small free program hosted on GitHub. The End-User License Agreement shown when installing had a few things, but what stood out was:

> [...] is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial
> 4.0 International License. Summary and full text of license and is avaliable here: https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/4.0/
>
> By using [...] Web Services you confirm that you are agree with respective terms and conditions listed here: [...] as well as Privacy Policy: [...]

The main use for GibHub is as issue tracker. The source GitHub repository only contains a README.md file and zip file containing the `.msi` installation file. There's even a few forks from new accounts, but they can't do much.

My main question is, what legal purpose does licensing a program with permissive licence have when the source code is not available? Are there likely to be any unintended consequences by licensing binaries under a permissive license?

Answer (score 3):

CC BY-NC is not a [permissive license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permissive_software_licence). Neither the FSF nor the OSI approved it, so it’s not a free software license nor an open source license. The reason is the "NC" part: the licensed work may not be used for commercial purposes.

CC BY-NC and the other CC licenses aren’t intended for code, so they don’t clarify code-related aspects. This means there is no requirement to license/distribute the source code when licensing/distributing the binary.

A binary licensed under CC BY-NC is essentially proprietary [freeware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freeware) which anyone may share in a non-commercial way, and use for non-commercial purposes. But if the source code can be extracted from the binary, it should fall under the same license, too.

Comment: Freeware that can be freely shared with others (a step up from freeware that can only legally be downloaded from the source.)